# Visibility of Sliding Panel not Working / Delay Paint Issue?

Tags: winforms, panel, sliding

Panel p2 is not showing up until width of Panel 1 is 0.  However, if I uncomment the messageBox code, p2 renders when the messageBox appears.   This leads me to think that C# natively delays a repaint on p2 until some other event (e.g., messageBox) which forces a UI paint.

How can I get around this?

```
    private void SlidePanel(UIPanel p, UIPanel p2)  //, Direction d)
    {
        int prevWidth = p.Width;
        PanelDockStyle prevDock = p.DockStyle;
        p.DockStyle = PanelDockStyle.Left;

        p2.Show();

        while (p.Width > 0)
        {
            p.Width -= (p.Width > 4 ? 4 : p.Width);
            Thread.Sleep(1);

            //if (p.Width < 400)
            //{
            //    MessageBox.Show("Ha");
            //    break;
            //}
        }

        p.Hide();
        p.DockStyle = prevDock;
        p.Width = prevWidth;
    }
```

Answer (score 0):

p2.Refresh().   That's what happens when you write code at 6:00 a.m. in the morning.   :-|

Comment: Meh, that's what happens when you don't understand the UI dispatcher loop at 2:00 pm in the afternoon :)